# Facebook FBLoginView Custom loginView button internet issue

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk, reachability

Hi  every one,

```
    I'm developing app,it having login with face book functionality.For this i have used Facebook iOS SDK 3.18.1 version. I have created custom FBLoginView with custom button.every thing work properly. I had one issue if there is no internet connectivity i need to show alert like 'network requires' but when click on custom login button it directly move to safari browser with out checking network.I have written code for check network connectivity using rechablity.When i click on facebook custom login button it directly move to safari browser for facebook login.
```

So can any one help me to solve this issue?

here is the code:

```
-(void)showFacebookLoginUI
{
    self.loginview =
    [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",@"public_profile",@"user_about_me",@"user_hometown",@"user_location",nil]];


    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        self.loginview.frame = CGRectMake(80, 380, 200, 40);
    }else if(IS_IPAD){
        self.loginview.frame = CGRectMake(310, 636, 180, 100);
    }else{
       self.loginview.frame = CGRectMake(80, 330, 150, 40);
    }
    for (id obj in self.loginview.subviews)
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton * loginButton =  obj;

            UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fbIcon.png"];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fblogin:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
             UILabel *label =obj;
            [label removeFromSuperview];          
        }
    }

    [self.view addSubview:self.loginview];
}
-(void)fblogin:(id)sender
{

    if (![self.sharedObject CheckInternetConnectivity]) {

        [self.sharedObject showAlertWithMessage:kNetworkRequiresMessage];
    }
    else{
        self.loginview.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

In fblogin method it directly navigate to safari browser for face book login without checking net connectivity.

Comment: in Facebook button first check the network is available or not, if internet is not available show the alert else part call the allowing ui method

Comment: Hi Karthik..Thank for your response.Can you check the fblogin method there i'm checking net connection first,if not i will displaying  alert also.but when click on login button it directly move to safari browser for facebook login after CheckInternetConnectivity called ..that is my issue? I hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below.

```
        loginFacebook =
        [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"user_friends",nil] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends];

        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        self.loginview.frame = CGRectMake(80, 380, 200, 40);
        }else if(IS_IPAD){
        self.loginview.frame = CGRectMake(310, 636, 180, 100);
        }else{
        self.loginview.frame = CGRectMake(80, 330, 150, 40);
        }

        for (id obj in loginFacebook.subviews)
        {
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                UIButton * loginButton =  obj;

                UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook_off_signin.png"];
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

                //[loginButton sizeToFit];
            }
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                UILabel * loginLabel =  obj;
                loginLabel.text =@""; //@"Log in to facebook";
                loginLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                loginLabel.frame =CGRectMake(123,149, 280, 55);// CGRectMake(0, 0, 271, 37);
            }
        }

        loginFacebook.delegate = self;
      [self.view addSubview:loginFacebook];
```

You don't give to add Target of button when you ckick on Button of Facebook then its delegate is called.

if although button image is not display then try remove comment of `[loginButton sizeToFit];`
from the code. it working.